# TFLearn cannot feed value of shape (ValueError) when trying to create a simple addition model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression, tflearn

I'm new to TFLearn and trying to create a simple addition program.
The input is 2 values and the output is one value, which is the sum of the inputs. The error I'm getting is `"ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)"` It seems like the shape/batch size matches in the code, so I don't know if the way the train/test data is generated is the problem, or if the NN creation code is wrong.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tflearn


def generate_answers(data):
    answers = []
    for row in data:
        answers.append(sum(row))
    return np.array(answers).astype(float)

train_data_count = 1000
test_data_count = 100

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=(None, 2))
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation="linear")
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_square', metric='R2', learning_rate=0.1)
model = tflearn.DNN(net)

train_data = np.random.randint(500, size=(train_data_count, 2)).astype(float)
train_answers = generate_answers(train_data)
print(train_data.shape)
print(train_answers.shape)
model.fit(train_data, train_answers, n_epoch=100, batch_size=100, show_metric=True)

test_data = np.random.randint(500, size=(test_data_count, 2)).astype(float)
test_answers = generate_answers(test_data)
predictions = model.predict(test_data)

count = 0
for i in range(len(predictions)):
    if test_answers[i] == predictions[i]:
        count += 1
print(count, "/", len(predictions))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that adding `net = tflearn.reshape(net, [-1])` before the regression helped solve that issue. The program still has some bugs, but at least that is solved.